# How to use phantomjs as npm package

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am writing a node script that require phantomjs and I want to share that script with someone else and he should be able to run script without installing phantomjs separately in his system.

I have tried installing it like this in my node script (that has package.json file as well).

```
npm install --save phantomjs
```

And I then trying to run script as given in [phantomjs home page](http://phantomjs.org/)

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```

It says can't find module webpage. If I install webpage separately like

```
 npm install --save webpage
```

Then it says, create is not a function.

Is there a way I can work with phantomjs without downloading and installing it in system?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS initially was a separate binary, not a npm module, and if you want to run a script as it is presented on its own page then run it like this

```
/path/to/phatomjs /path/to/script.js
```

If you dont want your users to install it, you can create a program that will install it for them and maybe run scripts. I once used Innosetup installer and nwjs for this purpose.

---

And if you want to use PhantomJS in an npm module, you can use the [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) package, but the syntax for creating scripts will be different, see example on the package page and also in [examples folder](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/tree/master/examples)